# What does the generic Schema type do when creating a new Schema in Mongoose with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

The Typescript section in the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html) shows the following example for a strongly typed Schema:

```js
import { Schema, model, connect } from 'mongoose';

// 1. Create an interface representing a document in MongoDB.
interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  avatar?: string;
}

// 2. Create a Schema corresponding to the document interface.
const schema = new Schema<User>({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  avatar: String
});

// 3. Create a Model.
const UserModel = model<User>('User', schema);
```

Here they add a generic User type to the Schema definition calling it a *"Schema corresponding to the document interface"* however it's not explained what this means.

Further down in the docs it says: *"You as the developer are responsible for ensuring that your document interface lines up with your Mongoose schema. For example, Mongoose won't report an error if `email` is `required` in your Mongoose schema but optional in your document interface."*

This means that adding the type to the Schema generic will not throw any type errors when the interface and Schema definition don't line up. So what does it do?

Comment: A bit out of topic but from experience, having strong types with TS and Mongoose + MongoDB (NoSQL db) usually really don't work well. 80% of the time, a relational database will be more convenient as the "types" are also checked at the database level, not just at the ORM level. There are much more advanced solutions nowadays such as Prisma ORM: https://www.prisma.io/ .

Comment: @Hugo yes I noticed that too, trying to set up proper strict types with Mongoose is often very inconvenient and unclear if it even works. The TS docs on Mongoose are pathetic and don't really explain anything. Most online tutorials even interfere with some info from the docs and do things entirely different. I'll look into prisma.io.